# Google Chrome tab(s) crash during CLI serverless deploy

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, zsh, serverless-framework, iterm2

Over the years, with many Macbooks, MacOS & software versions, I've been consistently facing Google Chrome tab(s) crashes while a `serverless deploy` command is running in my terminal.

Everything is fine, then I launch a `serverless deploy` with any options/envVars, and at a random moment of this process (packaging, uploading, whatever...), from 1 to *n* Google Chrome tabs are, all at the same time, ending up like this:

[image: screen capture]

*(excuse the French)*

Refreshing the relevant crashed tabs just does the trick, depending on what you were actually doing out there you'd have to reconnect, rebrowse, re-whatever, re-everything

Sometimes (~5% of the time) it's "all of Google Chrome" that actually crahes: each window (and obviously each tab it contains) is closed like if I killed the process, and I have to relaunch it all.

This looks extremely weird to me, and obviously is pretty annoying! Trying to find the link between a terminal and Google Chrome I'm guessing Node.js might be something to look at, but I'm at loss finding any question/forum/content about this issue. Yet, I've got a pretty standard config, so I'm pretty sure I'm not alone there.

Anyone facing the same tabs crash with a solution to share?  Any pointers about what the problem might be or where I should keep digging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have experienced this too and had the same exact behaviour with chrome tabs crashing when running the serverless deploy command. I narrowed it to serverless opening too many files ( more than the default limit you might have ) when running the deploy command which is causing the chrome tabs unable to use required resources and crashing. Try to increase your ulimit and check if it happens again.

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks a lot for your help @Tadaka 

Comment: `sudo launchctl limit maxfiles 2048 unlimited` (just reinstalled, searched it forever, now I'll found it right where I'll look )